# Write business logic with reactive database

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm writing an reactive api that send notifications to android phones.
**The process to send notification needs to access a token code from a phone to push the message to it**. To achieve this I created an endpoint on the server side to recieve the token from the phone.
My problem is to save the token and then use it on the process described above.
This is the TokenController, TokenService, TokenRepository and Token POJO:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TokenController {

    @Autowired
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/token",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> newToken(@RequestBody Token token) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenService.save(token));
    }
} 

//--------------------------------------------------------------- 

@Service
public class TokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {

    @Autowired
    private TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    public Mono<Token> save(Token token) {
        return tokenRepository.save(token);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------- 

@Repository
public interface TokenRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Token, Long> { }

//---------------------------------------------------------------

@Data
@Document(collection = "token")
public class Token {

    @Id
    private Long _id;

    private Long clientCode;

    private String tokenKey; // VALUE THAT IS NEEDED ON NOTIFICATION
}
```

To send notification, I have a notification controller that need to access the database and look for the token. Reading reactive aproach I couldn't understand how to read the dababase, using TokenRepository, inside my notification service, and use something like "findById" method to retrieve the token. How could I use the returned Mono object and get the property "tokenKey"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ResponseEntity<Mono<Token>>` you should have `Mono<ResponseEntity<Token>>` try this

```
 public @ResponseBody Mono<ResponseEntity<Token>> newToken(@RequestBody Token token) {
        return tokenService.save(token)
               .map(t -> ResponseEntity.ok(t));
    }
```

You are wrapping your mono inside an object, which doesn't get subscribed, so reverse this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could store the future result in a `CompletableFuture` and then when it completes, store the Token object.
Here is a example of it:

```
CompletableFuture<Token> tokenFuture = tokenRepository.findByClientCode(notificationRequest.getClientCode()).toFuture();

Token token = tokenFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It waits for 5 seconds for it or throw a `TimeoutException`

Comment: that seems to go against the whole reactive flow that webflux is trying to promote.

Comment: @JamesRalston I am bit a new to the reactive concept, I'm still waiting for a better approach to solve this problem

Comment: I would go with the above answer. It is the correct way. I